# AJAX duplicate call

Tags: jquery, ajax

This question has been answered many times but Those can not help me out. 
I have tried to do AJAX call from a form but some reason it called double time.

```
var requestVendor = false;
$("#vendor").change(function() {
    var value = $("#vendor option:selected").val(); 

    var courseURL = host.concat("/admin/getcourse");


    if (requestVendor !=true) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: courseURL,
            data: {"id": value},
            success: function (response) {
                // done something here 
                requestVendor = true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[image]

How to prevent that duplicate call. It's driving me crazy right now.

Comment: You likely execute the change elsewhere too - can you show more code? Perhaps you are using some plugin to style the select that creates some more dom elements

Comment: I didn't do anything with `#vendor` select box any where. My back-end part is done by Phalcon(PHP framework)

Comment: I think it may be caused by the double event response of $('#vendor').change() event. try to add  console.log("Hello") to the first line of this event listener to have a double check

Comment: Did you debug and check if the `change` event function is not executing twice before the ajax `success` callback?

Comment: did you test what @KelvinYe advised?

Comment: I checked with `console.log('hello')`. It prints two times in console. @ Kelvin Ye

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be duplicate js`(jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js)` you are using in your project or you can check it out to comment it if you are using.

Hope it will help.